# Abel's test question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was looking the proof in http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch9.pdf in page 12. They prove Abel's test. The thing is I don't know where does the hypothesis of monotonicity of $g_n(x)$ is used. Also, in (**) he says $|F_n(x)-F_m(x)|< \frac{\epsilon}{M+1}$, but if you put $\frac{\epsilon}{M+1}$ in  the summatory in (*), that thing it's not even bounded, you get $(n-m)\frac{\epsilon}{M+1}$. I am wrong?

Comment: I agree that it looks to have a mistake in the proof.